# Merge two nested observables into one

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, rxjs

I would like to merge two nested observables into one. The first one listens for valueChanges on an input an the second one then queries the database. The expected result (for me) is to have one observable which I can use with an async pipe in my Angular template.

In the example below the `filteredUsers$` variable is of the type  `Observable<Observable<MyUser[] | null>>` and I would like to have just `Observable<MyUser[] | null>`.

The `userControl` is an Angular `FormControl`.

```
this.filteredUsers$ = this.userControll.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300)).pipe(
        map((newSearch) => {
            if (newSearch) {
                return this.userSearchGql
                    .fetch({
                        where: {
                            OR: [
                                { firstname: { contains: newSearch } },
                                { secondname: { contains: newSearch } },
                                { email: { contains: newSearch } }
                            ]
                        }
                    })
                    .pipe(
                        map((res) => {
                            return res.data.users;
                        })
                    );
            }
            return null;
        })
    );
```

**Edit 1**

I think I fixed it thanks to @Jules answer

```
this.filteredUsers$ = this.userControll.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300)).pipe(
        switchMap((newSearch) => {
            if (newSearch === null) {
                return of(null);
            }
            return this.userSearchGql
                .fetch({
                    where: {
                        OR: [
                            { firstname: { contains: newSearch } },
                            { secondname: { contains: newSearch } },
                            { email: { contains: newSearch } }
                        ]
                    }
                })
                .pipe(
                    map((res) => {
                        return res.data.users;
                    })
                );
        })
    );
```

Comment: Try the https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree.

Comment: Remember to subscribe after using pipe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to switch observable, I think this should work.

```
this.filteredUsers$ = this.userControll.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300)).pipe(
        map((newSearch) => {
            if (newSearch) {
                return switchMap((newSearch) => this.userSearchGql
                    .fetch({
                        where: {
                            OR: [
                                { firstname: { contains: newSearch } },
                                { secondname: { contains: newSearch } },
                                { email: { contains: newSearch } }
                            ]
                        }
                    }))
            }
            return null;
        }),
        map((res) => {
           return res ? res.data.users : null;
        })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Unfortunately, I get a "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction  >'." error for the pipe after switchMap

Comment: It's the right operator, but this isn't how to apply it at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, I changed my answer a bit